# 「切ってしまってから、切りすぎちゃった、なんて思いませんか。」「やっぱり後ろでも止められるぐらいにしようかな。」

Tags: meaning

> 1 - 男：短くってどのぐらいですか。肩の辺りまで？
> 2 - 女：うーん、切るなら耳が見えるぐらいかな。
> 3 - 男：それもお似合いかもしれませんが、切ってしまってから、切りすぎちゃった、なんて思いませんか。
> 4 - 女：そうねえ、それじゃ、やっぱり後ろでも止められるぐらいにしようかな。
> 5 - 男：顎の線くらいですね、前髪はどうしましょう？

Can someone explain what lines 3 and 4 mean?
This is what I don't get:

> 男：切ってしまってから、切りすぎちゃった、なんて思いませんか。
> 女：やっぱり後ろでも止められるぐらいにしようかな。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are talking about how much hair to cut.  The man perhaps is a hair stylist and the woman is a customer.

3. That (cutting up to your ear is visible) might be good to you, but you might realize this was too short after I cut that much.
4. I see. Then I would keep my hair so I can tie them up on the back.

Frankly, the man is suggesting cutting up to the ears are visible can be too much and the woman may regret, and the woman agrees.

Comment: Thanks for the translation, what word means tie up hair in the back?  Is it 止められるぐらい?  Doesn't that mean be stopped? stopped cutting?

Comment: @fynxgloire see meaning 6 here: https://jisho.org/word/%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B.

Comment: 止める in this context does not mean to stop cutting. 「後ろで止める」 means keep the hair fixed on the back head using something like band or hairpin.

Comment: @KotaMori Thank you.  Your comment makes the use of even just the use of the kanji 止 much clearer.